# How to load some default log4j config if fails init with env. specific config?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I work on logging improvement and faced with such problem. In our project there a lot of standalones which build using one common project with common configs and libs. For logging used log4j 1.2.15 and in every standalone used log4j init bean that load enviroment specific-configuration base on enviroment name:

```
<bean id="log4jConfigurer-bean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/env/log4j-${env.name}.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(we just make file-name of config from log4j.{env.name}.xml in our dirs).

In some cases our common lib used by other project (and we suppose can be used by some other project) where we really don`t know how enviroment will be called. In this case when var ${env.name} some unknown name for us, of cousre there is no config file for logging in our config dir.

So how can I make possible in case if file config/env/log4j-${env.name}.xml was not found load some default config file? We are not talking only this way of implementation of enviroment specific config (using spring bean level), but it is also possible to upgrade log4j to version 2 or switch to other logger with similar functional in case if its configs could implement enviroment specific load on configs level (may be some kind of config inheretance)?

May be I just not used all power of log4j config and I can make enviroment specific appender in one config file using some logic connected to enviroment variable? Any variant and ideas?

Comment: Try to split the huge block of text in your question into individual paragraphs; it's hard to read as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "out of the box" solution.

Instead of using `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`, create your own bean that validates the parameter and then calls `Log4jConfigurer.initLogging()`.

Alternatively, pass this new bean a list of configs and let it try each in turn.